# How to handle logging and imports when running a python module as the main script?

Tags: python, python-import, conventions, python-logging

I have a python library/package that contains modules with functions & classes I usually import inside of my application's main script. However, these modules each contain their own 'main()' function so that I can run them individually if needed. Here's an example:

```py
# my_module.py

import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class SomeModuleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def some_module_function():
    pass



def main():
    # Some code when running the module as the main script

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have two questions related to running this module as the main script (i.e. running `python my_module.py`):

1. What's the cleanest way to use the logging module in this case? I usually simply overwrite the global 'log' variable by including the following in the `main()` function, but I'm not sure if there's a more pythonic way of doing this:

```py
def main():
    # ... some logging setup
    logging.config.dictConfig(log_cfg_dictionary)

    global log
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

2. Is it considered good practice to include `import` statements inside of the `main()` function for all libraries only needed when running the script as main? For instance, one might need to use `argparse`, `json`, `logging.config`, etc. inside of the main function, but these libraries are not used anywhere else in my module. I know the most pythonic way is probably to keep all the import statements at the top of the file (especially if there's no significant difference in terms of memory usage or performance), but keeping main function-specific imports inside of `main()` remains readable & looks cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Regarding 1: I don't know of a better solution, I do it pretty much like that normally. Regarding 2: if running as main or as library differs that significantly, have you considered extracting the running as main logic into a separate runner file? may not always be a desirable solution, but in some instances I found it quite handy.

Comment: That's a good point! This has been my strategy as of a few weeks ago, but I felt like there were tooo many files in my project. That's why I started to include all of the 'main' stuff inside the modules themselves.

Comment: You can never have too many files in your project - it means you're keeping your files short. ;-) But really, I think it just has to work well for you and the audience you have in mind with your project. As long as that's given, either option should be fine.